# shall i write apexPages.messages in the dependent classes of controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, community, scheduled-apex

shall i write apexPages.messages in the dependent classes of controller? is it displayed on the page if we it meets the criteria.
Lets take i have vf page A, Which has B has controller and c is the dependent class for Controller.
If i write ApexPages.message in c.

If the criteria meets shall it show it as error message on the vf page??

Comment: Yes it should .........

Comment: Try `system.debug(ApexPages.currentPage());` in "c" dependent class method that you're calling from B. you will see the vf page reference.

Comment: if the dependent class C is shared in non VF use cases, then I'd say "NO" and instead the dependent class should return a list of some inner class objects, similar to how `Database.SaveResult` works for `database.xxx` methods -- or -- throw exceptions to be caught by its callers. This is a bigger discussion  centered around architecture patterns, covered elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

PageMessages are not dependent on the Classes or how are they calling each other. They are related to current page instance, which is invoking the Class functions.

Therefore, when you are adding any pages messages, ApexPages page instance will collect all page messages and will display them on the page.

```
ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Invalid Input.');
ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
```

So to answer your question, it will show the error on the page.